building to .net framework and .net
I Am trying to build to 2 frameworks.  we currently have a website running on .net framework 4.7.1
I am trying to facilitate a move to .net8.0 For now i want our website and all referenced classes to build to these 2 framework.
Googling around told me i should add this in the csproj file:
<TargetFrameworks>net8.0;net471</TargetFrameworks>

however after doing this i get following error:
The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

What is the correct way to build to these 2 frameworks?

.NET 8 is .NET Core 8, a completely different runtime and SDK. To work in Visual Studio you need to install the Developer pack as well. Have you installed the .NET Framework SDK? Have you followed the link in the error message to install the the missing developer pack?

Does your machine have a different version of .NET Framework perhaps?

@PanagiotisKanavos this website clearly states net8.0 is the .NET8 framework? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-target-frameworks
Also i did follow the link and installed developer pack for 4.7.1,

No it doesn't say this at all. The last version of .NET Framework is 4.8. .NET 5 and later are .NET Core versions. The Core part was removed for marketing reasons.

@PanagiotisKanavos well i have installed the developer pack for .net framework 4.7.1 and also installed the SDK for .net 8.0.  So what SDK am i missing then? there is no .net4.0 SDK? and the framework one is installed (and was installed before as i have been developing in it for years)

Check this possibly related question .NET 4.0 build server reference assemblies warnings MSB3644. Are you building on a build server with the wrong bitness or old Windows?

Do you get that error when building for Windows only? If your code references a .NET Framework library, the .NET 8 build will complain.

if i add it like this, it works:
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<TargetFrameworks>net8.0</TargetFrameworks>

Not sure if this is the correct ay, but n build errors anymore
